# Transpose of a 3D tensor

Tags: keras, tensorflow, loss-function, custom-layer

I need to transpose a 3-dimensional tensor of the shape (batch_size, N, M) to (batch_size, M, N) in a custom loss function in Keras with tensorflow as the backend. I tried using the following function

`K.permute_dimensions(y_true,(0,2,1))`

It gives me an error that the dimension must be 2 instead, 3 is given.

When I try to input the following

`K.permute_dimensions(y_true,(1,0))`

it says the dimension is 3, instead, 2 is given.

I also tried using K.transpose but it gives me (M,N,batch_size).

I already implemented the solution with for loop, but in keras custom loss, for loops should be avoided.

```
from keras import backend as K
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    beta  = K.permute_dimensions(y_pred, (0,2,1))
```

Comment: When you do `y_true.shape` what values do you get? Also give the values for each `batch_size, N, M`.

Comment: @Memristor For `y_true.shape` I got `(batch_size, N, M)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tf.transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) instead:

```py
tf.transpose(y_true, perm=(0, 2, 1))
```

Otherwise use `tf.keras` instead of simply `keras`, as follows:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    beta = K.permute_dimensions(y_pred, (0, 2, 1))
    # ...
```

Comment: both approaches didn't work out for me. Did you try it, if yes, please mention the TF and Keras version.

Comment: @DocJazzy Yes I tried both on TF and Keras v2.8.0. What happens if you reshape the tensor? For example `x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(M, N, batch_size))`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It was a problem with the keras version, I installed the latest version, and it works without any problem.